# Import Excel sheet data starting from specific row and columns to datagrid then into SQL Server table, WPF

Tags: sql-server, excel, wpf

I am trying to import an Excel sheet generated by A system into my SQL Server table using my WPF application. The problem is that the Excel sheet has a title written over the first 4 rows as below:

[image]

What I want to do is: ignore the first 4 rows and start reading from the table's columns title; read specific columns and ignore the first column and read the second and the fourth one.

After reading the data, I want to show it in WPF datagrid, then import it into a SQL Server table.

Any suggestions or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, how to skip the rows and columns

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Title = "Test Cases Excel File ..";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                txt_FilePath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;


                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
                excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
                // Opening Excel file
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txt_FilePath.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

                worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                range = worksheet.UsedRange;

                int column = 0;
                int row = 0;
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Essential YN");
                dt.Columns.Add("Test Area");
                dt.Columns.Add("Test Part");
                dt.Columns.Add("Test Item");
                dt.Columns.Add("Comment");
                dt.Columns.Add("Result");


                for (row = 5; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (column = 1; column <= 6; column++)
                    {
                        dr[column - 1] = (range.Cells[row, column] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                workbook.Close();
                excelApp.Quit();

                // Binding to DataGridView
                DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```